# My Awk command sorts, but unexpectedly omits duplicates

Tags: sorting, awk

Im trying to sort this file by a specific field, and I want to do it all in `awk`:

```
"firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

I use this command:

```
awk -F'.*"firstName": "|",.*"lastName": "|",' '{b[$3]=$0} END{for(i in b){print i}}' sumacomando
```

which outputs:

```
111
222
444
555
```

but I expected:

```
111
111
222
222
444
444    
555
```

That is, while the actual output is seemingly sorted, as desired, it is unexpectedly missing duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The ordering of keys/indices in `awk`'s arrays, which are always *associative* arrays (dictionaries), is an implementation detail - no particular order is guaranteed; in your case the output just *happened to be* sorted.
- keys are *unique*, so if `$3` in more than 1 input row has the same value, the `b[$3]=...` assignments *overwrite each other* - the last one wins.

You therefore:

- have to use a sequentially indexed array to store your 3rd field values (`$3`)
- have to sort the resulting array by its values *later*.

Per the POSIX Awk spec, Awk has no built-in sort functions, but *GNU* `awk` does, enabling the following solution with its `asort()` function:

```
awk -F'.*"firstName": "|",.*"lastName": "|",' '
  { b[++n]=$3 } END{ asort(b); for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print b[i] }
' sumacomando
```

Note that this doesn't include storing the associated full lines (`$0`).

---

If you also want to store the associated full lines while still performing the sorting in (GNU) Awk, it gets more complicated:

```
awk -F'.*"firstName": "|",.*"lastName": "|",' '
  # Use a compound key to store the value of $3 plus a sequential index
  # to disambiguate, and store the input row ($0) as the value.
  { vals[$3,++n]=$0 }
  END{     
    # Sort by compound key using the helper function defined below.
    asorti(vals, names, "cmp_func");
    # Output the first half of the compound key, i.e., the value of $3,
    # followed by the associated input row.
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print gensub(SUBSEP ".*$", "", 1, names[i]), vals[names[i]]
  }
  # Helper sort function that splits the compound key into its components
  # - $3 value and sequential index - and compares the $3 values alphabetically
  # and the indices numerically.
  function cmp_func(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
    split(i1, tokens1, SUBSEP)
    split(i2, tokens2, SUBSEP)
    if (tokens1[1] < tokens2[1]) return -1
    if (tokens1[1] > tokens2[1]) return 1
    i1 = int(tokens1[2])
    i2 = int(tokens2[2])
    if (i1 < i2) return -1
    if (i1 > i2) return 1
    return 0
  }
' sumacomando
```

---

Piping to `sort` as an alternative solution greatly simplifies matters:

```
awk -F'.*"firstName": "|",.*"lastName": "|",' '{ print $3, $0 }' sumacomando | sort -k1,1
```

Note, however, that the pure Awk solution above preserves the input order among duplicate `$3` values, which the `sort`-assisted solution does not.

Conversely, the pure Awk solution needs to store all input in memory at once, whereas the `sort` utility is optimized to work with large input sets and uses temporary files on demand.

Comment: hi sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

your choice of field separator is unconventional, perhaps better use this instead

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                  if($i~"\"lastName\"") 
                      {gsub(/"/,"",$(i+1)); 
                       print $(i+1)}}' file | sort
```

if your `awk` has `asort` function you can do this instead

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                 if($i~"\"lastName\"") 
                    {gsub(/"/,"",$(i+1)); 
                     a[++c]=$(i+1)}} 
          END {asort(a); 
               for(k=1;k in a;k++) print a[k]}' file
```

Comment: Good answer thank you very much but I am looking like doing it entirely with awk for different reasons; But if I do not find another answer I will choose you as best answers

Comment: awk has asort??

Comment: `gawk` has, it's not part of "classical" `awk` since against the original unix tooling philosophy

Answer (score 1):

@victorhernandezzero: @try: I tried with a different approach, I hope it may help you/all too. With only single awk(no other commands).

```
awk '/lastName/{getline;while(!$0){getline};A[$0]} END{num=asorti(A, B);for(i=1;i<=num;i++){print B[i]}}' RS='[: ",]'   Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** Above solution will not give the duplicates which you need, special  thanks to mklement0 for letting me know, following may help you in same too.

```
awk '/lastName/{getline;while(!$0){getline};A[++j]=$0} END{num=asort(A, B);for(i=1;i<=num;i++){print B[i]}}' RS='[: ",\n]'  Input_file
```

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to improve your question.
The sorting part of your answer is now identical to the 1st solution in my answer (except that you duplicate the array, which isn't necessary).
The value-extraction part didn't need rewriting to begin with - the OP's command worked fine in that respect - and your rewrite is
complicated and involves `getline`, which is rarely the right tool to use. It also makes the solution harder to generalize.
P.S.: Please don't @-mention the OP in your answers. The OP is notified of answers anyway, and it's a distraction to future readers.

Comment: hi sorry this is a confusion this command works because a install gawk but not works native with nawk or awk sorry for all